# Software for capturing and editing packets for Windows

Tags: windows, network-monitor, proxy, packet-capture

I'm looking for software that can capture and edit packets (before they "reach" my computer). Like Fiddler, but for another ports and protocols.

Answer (score 0):

[WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is the obvious, industry standard, tool to record and decode packets for ***many*** protocols.  I am unaware of any equal.

While I have never used it to modify the packets in transit, Google indicates that it can be done. Search for `modify packets using wireshark`, watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcQHE6Z3Ghc) and read the other search results.

If I were you, I would look no further. If it has any possible downside, it might be that it is too powerful and full-featured ;-)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with Wireshark, but as far as I know, it only allows editing captured packets, meaning editing only the log files/records (I don't know how they are called exactly). I want to edit them in run time before my computer processes them.

Comment: My bad. Sorry. Since I have not done this myself, I can say no more. I am sure that you can Google just as well as I. If you do find a way, would you please come back and post an answer? That would be of great help to others. Good luck. I have marked this question as a favo(u)rite :-)